# How do the labels in nasm work , in case of loading code in a specific address?

Tags: assembly, label, nasm

I am trying to make an assembly bootloader (working in 16 bit real mode using nasm assembler and qemu ).
When i load the code after the first 512 bytes in a memory location (lets say 0x9000)  and try to print using somtehing like :

```
  mov ah , 0xe 
  mov al , byte [label]
  int 0x10
```

i get some irrelevant value printed . I tried to set the ds register also at the address 0x9000 using :

```
mov bx , 0x900
mov ds , bx
```

but still nothing seem to work .What could be the issue ? (When i use the specific adress where the value is set , everything works , but i want to use the labels ...)
The complete code i actually used:

```
;nasm -fbin boot7.asm -o boot7.iso && qemu-system-x86_64 -fda boot7.iso


[bits 16 ]
mov ax ,0x8e0 ; SET THE DS REG AT THE BEG NOT SURE Y I DID THAT 
mov ds , ax 

;LOAD MORE THAN 512 BYTES TO MEMORY 
;USING BIOS CALL
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mov [BOOT_DRIVE] , dl   ;
mov bp , 0x8000         ;SET BASE POINTER
mov sp , bp             ;


mov bx , 0x9000         ;POSITION TO PLACE THE DATA 
mov dh , 5              ;SECTORS TO READ 
mov dl , [BOOT_DRIVE ]  ;RETRIEVE BOOT DEVICE 

push dx         ; (CONTAINS SECTORS AND BOOT DRIVE)
mov ah , 0x2    ;
mov al , dh     ; SET THE OTHR PARAMS 
mov ch , 0      ;(SECTOR  ETC)
mov dh , 0      ;
mov cl , 2      ;

int 0x13
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mov ah , 0xe            ; 
mov bx , load_was_ok     ; 
                        ; print a value stored at  
one :                   ; 0x9000 (as i thought)
mov al , [bx]           ; 
int 0x10                ;  
inc bx                  ;INCREMENT AND CHECK 
cmp byte[bx] ,0         ;THE NEW 
jne one                 ; 

jmp 0x0900:0x0          ;SET THE CODE SEGMENT REGISTER (CODE WORKS FINE
                        ;WITH THIS ADDRESS)




BOOT_DRIVE : db 0,0
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

;mov ax , 0x900                      ; SET THE NEW DS 
;mov ds , ax                         ; REGISTER     

new_load_0x9000: 


jmp load_was_ok_end
load_was_ok: db 'if u see me i was loaded ', 0
load_was_ok_end:




mov ah , 0xe 
mov al , "o"
int 0x10


mov al , [simple_msg]  ;THIS IS REALLY 0X8E00+simple_msg (shouldnt it 
int 0x10               ; be 0x9000+simple_msg ?)

mov bx ,simple_msg 



start:
mov al , byte [bx]
int 0x10 
inc bx 
cmp bx , 1
jl start 



jmp $
simple_msg : db "7"
```

Comment: “When i use the specific adress where the value is set , everything works , but i want to use the labels”: `al` should contain one ASCII character value, so in the case `mov al, 'A'` you’ll see a single `A`. Otherwise `mov al, [label]` seems legit, presuming `label` is _not_ a _length-prefixed_ string.

Furthermore, ensure `bh` contains the correct page number and, if in color mode, `bl` a visible color. (You didn’t show us that code, so I’m just mentioning it.)

Comment: Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is loaded to linear address 9000h? If `es` has a value that differs from 0 when calling `int 13h`, the sector is loaded to `10h*es+9000h`.

Comment: im not sure , but since i make a `jmp 0x9000:0x0` and then the code there is being executed , i guess it was loaded

Comment: what i dont get is what the label actually is . Is it just an offset of the code generated , or an actual address ?   When  parts of the code are loaded in different memory locations you have to take into account the offset of  the code part from the beginning of the physical memory   and the offset of the label inside the code before the seperation  ? Seems like this to me but im not quite sure .